# Probability with one percentage

Tags: statistics

If 40% of people have watched TV today, what is the probability that the three people you pick haven't watched TV today? The people are randomly selected and not replaced. I've just been stumped on this problem even though I know I've done something similar.

Comment: What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: How are you picking the people? Even assuming equal probability in picking, you could pick with replacement or without.

Comment: We hope to see what you have tried and to know why you are not able to answer on your own. Please edit your Question to include your thoughts so far. // If you know about the binomial distribution, then let $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(3, .6).$ You seek $P(X=3).$

Comment: The people are randomly selected and they are not replaced

Comment: If $40\%$ of people watch TV, then what percentage of people didn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P(TV) = 0.4

P(Not TV) = 0.6

0.6 * 0.6 * 0.6 = **0.216 OR 21.6%**

This is assuming that it is a complementary scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Let A= watching tv. B= not watching tv.

$\\P(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\cap B_{3})$ are all independent events. So you can use the multiplication rule.

$\\P(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\cap B_{3}) = (P(B))^{3}=(0.6)^3$ It is important to know why you can do that.